# Forwarding and routing issues using linux bridge

Tags: iptables, routing, virtualbox, bridge

I have two containers running (A and B) inside a Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 18.04).
For network simulation purposes I am routing packets from A to B (this part works).
What I want to do is to allow A and B to communicate with the outside world.
Thus I would have :

```
A ---- B ---- Host VM --- Host --- Internet
```

I've done this so far :

```
ip link add name br_routing type bridge
ip link set dev br_routing up
```

Then add another virtual interface so container B has an interface to reach host vm network :

```
ip link add vm_side_iface type veth peer name containerb_side_iface
```

Add interface to the bridge

```
ip link set dev vm_side_iface master br_routing
```

Set ips for bridge and interface inside container

```
ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev br_routing
ip addr add 192.168.10.2/24 dev vm_side_iface
```

Activate interface on vm side

```
ip link set vm_side_iface up
ip link set containerb_side_iface netns $container_pid
```

Then inside container B network namespace :

```
ip addr add 192.168.10.2/24 broadcast 192.168.10.255 dev containerb_side_iface
ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev containerb_side_iface
```

At this point I'm able to ping A and B from the host virtual Machine

However I cannot ping beyond the bridge from A or B.
The error seems to come from routing so here it is :
B routing Table :

```
10.11.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.11.1.2
10.22.0.0/16 via 10.11.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.10.0/24 dev containerb_side_iface  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.2
```

host VM routing Table :

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev  enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 #Irrelevant here
10.11.0.0/16 via 192.168.10.2 dev br_routing #Route to reach B
10.22.0.0/16 via 192.168.10.2 dev br_routing #Route to reach A
192.168.10.0/24 dev br_routing proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 #This seems odd
192.168.10.0/24 dev router_0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2 #This seems odd
```

My second guess is my routing tables, this is what I've tried :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o vm_side_iface, -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i vm_side_iface, -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o vm_side_iface, -j ACCEPT
```

I also tried replacing **vm_side_iface** by **br_routing** but it would not work either way. Moreover, the rules are not used (0 accepted packets, 0 dropped). These are the only rules that are configured in the VM.
Regardless, the ping from the Host VM to A/B works without these rules.

Finally, **modprobe br_netfilter** and flushing files inside /etc/sys/net/bridge does not change anything.

What does not work :

```
ping from A or B to HOST VM
ping from A or B to vm_side_iface
ping from A or B to br_routing
```

What works :

```
ping from HOST VM to A or B
```

I've noticed that the messages get to the bridge (tcpdump -i br_routing) but are not forwarded to the enp0s3 interface.

Any guess ?

Comment: Bridges do not route packets, that's what routers do. Bridges switch frames.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by using the docker0 bridge that is created by default when starting docker containers without network parameters

```
docker run -itd image_name
```

The bridge is the same as the one I was creating but somehow this one works.